cordova error while building the android project using cordova build android command
when i want to build the cordova project i got this error .
i have java version 20 in my pc
and gradle version 8.3
How can i solve it ???enter image description here
C:\Users\Alire\OneDrive\Desktop\new app cordova\first>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Alire\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\src\src (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Alire\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.


Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0.
Required by:
project :
> No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
- Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')


Try:


Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Alire\OneDrive\Desktop\new app cordova\first\platforms\android\tools\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug
C:\Users\Alire\OneDrive\Desktop\new app cordova\first>
i try to change the gradle version and jdk version

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
